# Helm complicated array variable

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, helm3

In values.yaml I have defined

```
data_fusion:
    tags:
      - tag1
      - tag2
      - tag3
    instances:
      - name: test
        location: us-west1
        creating_cron: @once
        removing_cron: @once
        config:
          type: Developer
          displayName: test
          dataprocServiceAccount: 'my@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
        pipelines:
          - name: test_rep
            pipeline: '{"my_json":{}}'
      - name: test222
        location: us-west1
        creating_cron: @once
        removing_cron: @once
        config:
          type: Basic
          displayName: test222
          dataprocServiceAccount: 'my222@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
        pipelines:
          - name: test_rep222
            pipeline: '{"my_json222":{}}'
          - name: test_rep333
            pipeline: '{"my_json333":{}}'
          - name: test_rep444
            pipeline: '{"my_json444":{}}'
```

You guys can see I have 3 tags and 2 instances. The first instance contains 1 pipeline, the second instance contains 3 pipelines.

I want to pass tags and instances to my yaml file:

```
another_config: {{ .Values.blabla.blablabla }}
data_fusion:
    tags:
      - array of tags should be here
    instances:
      - array of instances (and associated pipelines) should be here
```

Or just simply

```
another_config: {{ .Values.blabla.blablabla }}
data_fusion:
    {{.Whole.things.should.be.here}}
```

Could you guys please help? Since I'm new to helm so I don't know how to pass the complicated array (or the whole big section of yaml).

Answer (score 1):

Helm includes an underdocumented `toYaml` function that converts an arbitrary object to YAML syntax.  Since YAML is whitespace-sensitive, it's useful to note that `toYaml`'s output starts at the first column and ends with a newline.  You can combine this with the `indent` function to make the output appear at the correct indentation.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
type: ConfigMap
metadata: { ... }
data:
  data_fusion: |-
{{ .Values.data_fusion | toYaml | indent 4 }}
```

Note that the last line includes `indent 4` to indent the resulting YAML block (two spaces more than the previous line), and that there is no white space before the template invocation.

In this example I've included the content as a YAML block scalar (the `|-` on the second-to-last line) inside a ConfigMap, but you can use this same technique anywhere you've configured complex settings in Helm values, even if it's Kubernetes settings for things like resource constraints or ingress paths.

Comment: Thanks, this task is suspended now. I will accept your answer later if it works